# SQL LOOP Pass values from Temp Table as parameters to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

Using SQL Server 2016, I have a huge query for our Finance Dept that uses `@Year` and `@FinPeriod` to match up transactions with a period. And for reporting we normally pass a single value into the stored procedure. But now we are required to populate the underlying tables with the data that would normally be generated on the fly.

Is there a loop anyone can help with please? I have a temp table with year values column and a finperiod for each of those years. I am looking to loop through this table - passing in both year and period to the stored procedure, one after the other until they have all been ran.

The stored procedure element is fine for me, just getting the loop/passing part to work would be a help.

So far I have:

```
 declare @fiscalyearid numeric(9)
 declare @FiscalYear numeric(9)
 declare @FiscalMonthOfYear numeric(9)
 declare @Year numeric(9)
 declare @FinPeriod numeric(9)

 if object_id('tempdb..#dateloop','u') is not null 
     drop table #dateloop

 select distinct 
     identity(int,1,1) as ID,
     FiscalYear_int, FiscalMonthOfYear 
 into 
     #dateloop 
 from 
     [DW].[DDS].[dimDate] 
 where 
     FiscalYear_int = '2018'

DECLARE C CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR --
    SELECT 
        ID, FiscalYear_int, FiscalMonthOfYear 
    FROM
        #dateloop;

OPEN C;

FETCH C INTO @FiscalYear, @FiscalMonthOfYear;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[Origen_Reporting->SSRS_Capex_Monitoring_Report_Expenditure]     @Year, @FinPeriod

    FETCH C INTO @Year,@FinPeriod
END 

CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```

Any tips would be brilliant. Thank you

Comment: you can join the entire table (Which has years) and get only required data..but this depends on how you are going to consume it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want your Cursor logic to work. Below is the code you can use to loop through your dates and call proc in loop.

```
DECLARE C CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR --
    SELECT 
        FiscalYear_int, FiscalMonthOfYear 
    FROM
        #dateloop;

OPEN C;

Fetch next  from c into @FiscalYear, @FiscalMonthOfYear

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN


    select  @FiscalYear, @FiscalMonthOfYear --exec proc passing these values
    EXEC [dbo].[Origen_Reporting->SSRS_Capex_Monitoring_Report_Expenditure]     @FiscalYear, @FiscalMonthOfYear
    FETCH next from c INTO @FiscalYear,@FiscalMonthOfYear
END 

CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```